# How to get Version of tooltipsy currently being used?

Tags: jquery

I want to know the version of jquery libraries I am using.

For example, in console

```
> $.fn.jquery // jquery version
> $.ui.jquery // jquery ui version
> $.effects.jquery // jquery effects version
```

I want to know how to find the version of jquery tooltipsy I am using?

Comment: Its unlikely the plugin author has put this functionality in the code. The best way is to check the comments at the top of the JS file.

Comment: Its an nonversioned project afaik so you'll never know

Answer (score 0):

Since he doesn't expose a version # you could simply create one yourself (for whatever version it is).

Just add:

```
$.fn.tooltipsy.version = '1.1.4'; // or whatever # you want
```

Then you can have all that data spit out with the rest of your version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The author didn't put the version number in the source file, so **it is impossible to get the version number with javascript**.

As far as I can see this project is not supported anymore, so I doubt that there will be any further versions.

You can check out the source code and the repo at [github](https://github.com/briancray/tooltipsy).